# How to bind a dynamically created object to the document ready event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that dynamically creates a slider element using the following code:

```
function NewDiv(){
        for (var count=0; count < parseFloat(sessvars.storey_count); count++)
            {
               var string="<br><div id='my-slider"+count+"' class='dragdealer'><div class='red-bar handle'><span id='drag-button"+count+"'>drag me</span></div></div>";
               $("body").append(string);

               var slider_id ="my-slider"+count;
               var drag_button_id = "drag-button"+count;

               //OBJECT GETS CREATED BELOW
               new Dragdealer(slider_id,{horizontal: true,x:Math.random(),animationCallback: function(x, y){
               document.getElementById(drag_button_id).innerHTML = x.toFixed(2);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

However, the `animationCallback` function which is invoked everytime the slider is moved has to be embedded within a function listener, and I have to somehow bind it to maybe the ready event. Is this the best way to make the slider update when its value changes? And if so, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: `and I have to somehow bind it to maybe the ready event` Huh? Why can't you just put your code in the callback?

Comment: Because the code in the callback is not executed when the slider's position is changed. It works fine for sliders that I create non-dynamically, just not for the sliders created using this function.

Comment: Just put your `NewDiv` invocation in a `ready` handler?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your `animationCallback` functions are closing over the same `drag_button_id` variable.
Therefore, they all update the last one.

You need to wrap the body of the `for` loop in a separate function so that each closure gets its own variable (because Javascript does not have block scope).

Comment: Sorry could you explain how it's closing over the same variable? What you said is correct because only the last slider works. However when I logged the `drag_button_id`, it seemed that the function was looping correctly. Why?

Comment: It'd be great if you could answer my question, but your link did help. Thans.

Comment: @Louis93: `drag_button_id` changes as the loop runs.  The callbacks only run after the loop finishes.